# How to destroy all parents of object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have model of tree imported from blender. It has few colliders attached to it each on different bone. I want to destroy whole tree when any of these colliders gets hit. I know that i can destroy parent of gameobject by using `transform.parent.gameobject` but bones are much often lower in the hierarchy. How can I achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform.root`. This will find the topmost object.

Comment: Thanks! If someone else needs to do that I did it like this: `Destroy(collider.transform.root.gameObject);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Transform.root` that returns the topmost transform in the hierarchy.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-root.html